# Create a dynamic select drop down list with php

Tags: php, xml

I have two drop down fields, one drop down select field has all the states in the US hardcoded. What I wanna do is when a user chooses a state, a php function is called that uses a api to collect the name of every single city in that state.

I already have the api and can access the xml data. What I cant figure out is how to trigger a php function when a state is selected with out having to press a button. Just select a state from the drop down list and show the cities in another drop down select list and if the state is changed then update the city list to show the cities from the current selected state.

Is this possible with just php? Or do I need something like ajax? Ive never worked with ajax.

Comment: You can do it either way, but if you want it to activate the next dropdown without reloading the page, you need to use ajax. I would recommend `jQuery ajax`, I have found that library to be really easy to use (I am not so great with javascript but I can get the `jQuery ajax` to work).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I will try jquery ajax. May I ask though, how would one go around with doing this with just php?

Comment: Without using javascript, you would need a `submit` button named "Proceed" or whatever that when you select the State and click submit, it reloads with the state saved in the `$_POST`. Then u run your API to grab the cities then show the pre-selected State dropdown, and now the city dropdown with a new submit button....and so forth and so on.

Comment: I see yea that is what I thought about doing before. I think using ajax might be a better way to present data. Thanks a bunch

Comment: It's definitely a better way! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You got to use ajax for that:

```
var state_id = selectedValue;// selected value of the state


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'city_api.php?state_id='+state_id,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {


                var output = '';
                    output += '<option value="NA">Select</option>';

                $(data).find("root").each(function() { //assuming first tag as root

                    $(this).find("city").each(function() {// assuming cities are inside city tag something like <city id="1">New York</city>

                        var city_name = $(this).text();
                        var city_id   = $(this).attr("id");

                        output  += '<option value="'+dst_id+'">'+dst_name+'</option>';

                   });
                });

                //output += '</select>';

                $('#city_dropdown').html(output);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('#city_dropdown').html('failure');
            }
        });
```

In place where you want dropdown to appear place

```
<div id="city_dropdown"></div>
```

Its not nessessary to be a div. you can use

,  etc.